# How to wire external power supply on stepper motor

Tags: arduino, power-supply, motor, raspberry-pi, stepper-motor

I followed [this tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-10-stepper-motors/hardware-uln2803) to setup my stepper motor.

Now my stepper needs 12V and not 5V. So I was wondering how I can add an external power supply without destroying my pi.

I found this:

[image: Arduino Wiring]

But it looks to me like the red wire from the pi is going nowhere.

Comment: You didn't mention the current that your motor requires but make sure that it's [within specs](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93083/33841) for ULN2803

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is supply 12V to pin 10 of the ULN2803 and the common wire of the stepper motor (the 5, red lead [here](http://www.adafruit.com/products/918#Technical_Details)). That is the reason the ULN2803 is used. It is simply an array of 8 Darlington pairs of BJTs with open collector output. The schematic of one pair is on the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf), page 2.

The Darlington pairs are used instead to one BJT to amplify more current. The amplified current from one BJT is fed into the base of the next to amplify even more. This configuration allows much current to be sunk from a small input source.

The open collector outputs allow the smaller logic input to be interfaced with larger supply voltages. Each pair of transistors will simply sink the load to ground, effectively turning it on. The downside is you cannot push a logic high to the load, but that isn't a concern for this situation since there is a common supply and each coil in the motor is energized by being sunk to ground.

Pin 10 of the ULN2803 is connected to the cathode of 8 diodes whose anodes go to each of the 8 outputs. These diodes are referred to as clamping diodes. When your supply is connected to this pin, it will prevent any of the output pins from rising above the supply voltage. This a useful feature for switching, inductive loads such as stepper motors that produce back-emf.

Comment: just to get it right. I wire the batery like in the arduino picture?

Comment: Correct. If anything, I would move the black wire to the other power rail on the breadboard. That way the black and red wires connecting the power and ground rails aren't needed.