# How to drive relay using uln2003

Tags: relay

I am designing a IR base home light control.
for this i use 6 relays and i try to driver it through uln2003. I connect the GND and COM wire with 12 volt power supply and input pins are connect to microcontroller which gives 5 volt supply but OUTPUT will become constant (about 1 to 1.5 voltage) and not change on any logic 0 or 1

Comment: circuit diagram?

Comment: You do know that a ULN2003 has open-collector outputs and will never drive them high?

Comment: [ULN2003](http://thank.you.for.including.a.datasheet.link) is a darlington transistor array. It is expected that the output voltage won't drop below 1 volt or so.

Comment: The uln2003 is an open collector device. For testing just add a resistor between the output and +12Volt. Or the relay...

Comment: Did you connect the ULN2003 ground to the microcontroller ground?

Comment: yes ground are connected

Comment: someone please tell me can i drive a relay using uln2003 if yes then how???

Comment: Connect the relay coil between 12V and the ULN2003 output.

Comment: For the correct connection scheme refer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93083/33841

Comment: uln 2003 does not amplifier the logical input signal. It can only make ground according to logical input. use upper diagram

Answer (score 4):

Here's something that should work:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The circuit below takes into account the open collector operation of the ULN2003. The diode D1 is to prevent kickback when deactivating the relay. Technically this diode is built into the ULN2003, but it never hurts to have an extra!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4np8S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's just crazy! The Darlington in the chip is a pair of NPNs, so the final emitter connection should in no way be connected to the positive side of V1, and the COM connection is the cathode of a diode designed to clamp the kickback of an inductive load to the positive rail when the inductive load is abruptly turned off. And, yet, two sheep support fantasy.

Comment: You're right, I mis-remebered the data sheet and got COM and E mixed up in my mind. Fixed!